# Maven jacoco excludes not working possibly due to uber jar

Tags: maven, jacoco-maven-plugin

In https://github.com/jimshowalter/architecture-enforcer, I'm trying to solve "Jacoco excludes in the pom aren't working for the pf-CDA classes, possibly due to the shaded jar. Because excludes aren't working, we can't enable the check for 100% statement and branch coverage." The pom seems to have the correct exclude entries, but the build begs to differ, so we had to comment out the thresholds in https://github.com/jimshowalter/architecture-enforcer/blob/master/pom.xml#L93.

Any idea why excludes aren't working?

Comment: After uncommenting mentioned lines build successfully finished. There is no package org.pfsw.* in src folder. Why do you want it to exclude? Am I missing something?

Comment: After N iterations on the pom, finally got it to work.

Comment: The org.pfsw class files wind up in the shaded jar. For some reason the N - 1 iterations I tried on the pom to get the report to exclude those files didn't work. I finally got it working. It's a bit creepy though, because it simply started working.

Comment: It works with the excludes as I had them.

Comment: But how did you made it work?

Comment: Exactly. When I was trying to get it to work before, I tried everything to exclude the pfsw classes, and nothing worked. Should have taken a screenshot. Then today I read Peter Saly's reply, tried it, and it magically worked. No idea why. I wouldn't have posted the question if it had worked before.